# How to make a alert if both inputs(password and re-type password) are not the same in form made out of PHP

Tags: php

I have made a signup page using PHP and I want to make a alert if both inputs(password and re-type password) in the form are not the same.

Comment: Ok and where are you stuck with that? What have you tried? Please provide the relevant parts of your current code so we have some context into which to put an answer as well. Not all forms are the same. See [ask] for more info

Comment: Hey, thanks for your question. Maybe you need to re-think what do you need. Do you need to validate on the front-end form? it's already done, right? if so, you need to verify in the back-end if you have both parameters and then if these are equals. Could you share your first approach, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a JavaScript `alert()` to the user, you can do this:

HTML:

```
<input type="password" name="pass">
<input type="password" name="retype_pass">
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $pass1 = $_POST['pass'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['retype_pass'];
    if($pass1 != $pass2) echo "<script>alert('Passwords are not same!');</script>";
?>
```